# Can't catch elements by id/classname

Tags: javascript

I have scrypt, that creates elements. It works, but when I try to catch product btns with class "product__btn" or with ID, I can't do it. So how can I catch created elements and why I can't catch them?

```js
function createProductsList(categoryName, productList) {

    const categoryBlock = document.querySelector('.category');
    const listTitle = document.createElement('p');
    
    listTitle.innerHTML = `<p class="category__name">${categoryName}</p>`;
    if(listTitle.classList.contains('category__name__remove')){
        listTitle.classList.remove('category__name__remove');
    }
    categoryBlock.prepend(listTitle);

    const productItems = productList.map(element => {
        const elem = document.createElement("div");
        elem.setAttribute("class", "product");
        elem.innerHTML = `
            <img class="product__image" src="${element.photo}" alt="">
            <p class="product__name">
                ${element.title.split("")
                               .map((titleStr, index) => titleStr = (index === 0) ? 
                                        titleStr.toUpperCase() : 
                                        titleStr.toLowerCase()).join("")}
            </p>
            <p class="product__description">
            ${element.composition.map((descriptionStr, index) => descriptionStr = (index === 0) ? 
                    descriptionStr = descriptionStr[0].toUpperCase() + descriptionStr.slice(1).toLowerCase() : 
                    descriptionStr = descriptionStr.toLowerCase()).join( ", " )}
            </p>
            <p class="product__price">${element.price}$</p>
            <button class="product__btn" id="${element.id}"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
            `;
        return elem;
    });

    const productListBlock = document.querySelector(".product-list");
    for (let product of productItems) {
        productListBlock.appendChild(product);
    }
}
//this code is in other file after calling function createProductsList
let test = document.getElementsByClassName('product__btn');
test.forEach(el=> console.log(el));
console.log(test, test[0]);
```

Comment: Where do you ever call your `createProductsList` function?  It looks like you defined a function which presumably (but hasn't been tested/confirmed) creates elements on the page, but you never call that function, and then right after defining it you try to find the elements it would have created if it had been called.

Comment: If you did call the function before trying to get the elements then it maybe some issue related to an async query for instance, depending on the context.

Comment: I make the project with few JS files and I tried to catch elements after function's call. Function is working well, but catching still doesn't work after calling function.

Comment: What is `element.composition` and how did it get there?

Comment: I have JSON files, where are all data about products, it doesn't matter. Problem is that I can't catch dynamically created elements in a variable/array.

Comment: Actually it does matter. If `element.composition` is not a valid array then the whole mess that you have provided just caves in. How do you expect anything to be tested if there's no example of input or what is expected as a result and what you actually get or the exact error logged as a result of running such a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't use forEach is that getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection – not an array (hence does not have the prototype method).

To work around this you can add each node from the collection to an actual array using`[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('xxx'))`

Note! because forEach takes a function as a parameter you can simply pass console.log to be automatically called with the element... `test.forEach(console.log)`does the same as`test.forEach(el => console.log(el))`

PS. I took the liberty to change the code a bit :-)

```js
createProductList('Category', [{
    photo: '//unsplash.it/160/160?random=1',
    title: 'Product one',
    price: 1000,
    id: 'A',
    composition: ['foo', 'bar']
  },
  {
    photo: '//unsplash.it/160/160?random=2',
    title: 'Product Two',
    price: 500,
    id: 'B',
    composition: ['baz', 'qux']
  }
]);



function createProductList(categoryName, productList) {

  const categoryElm = document.querySelector('.category');
  const productsElm = document.querySelector('.product-list');


  categoryElm.innerHTML = `<p class="category__name">${ categoryName }</p>`;

  productList.reduce((list, product) => {
    list.innerHTML += `
      <div class="product">
        <img class="product__image" src="${ product.photo }" alt="">
        <p class="product__name">
        ${ 
        product.title.split("")
          .map((title, index) => index ? 
            title.toLowerCase() : 
            title.toUpperCase()
          ).join("") 
        }
        </p>
        <p class="product__description">
        ${
        product.composition
          .map((descr, index) => index ? 
            descr.toLowerCase() :
            descr[0].toUpperCase() + descr.slice(1).toLowerCase()
          ).join( ", " )
        }
        </p>
        <p class="product__price">${ product.price }$</p>
        <button class="product__btn" id="${ product.id }">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
  `
    return list;
  }, productsElm)
}


//this code is in other file after calling function createProductsList
let test = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('product__btn'));
test.forEach(console.log);
console.log(test[0], test[1])
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.category {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: orangered;
}

.product-list,
.product {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="category"></div>
<div class="product-list"></div>
```